# Barcode Scanner in C# - How to access the ASCOM Myco 3 handset scanner optic

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, barcode-scanner

I am working on a Xamarin Form Mobile App for handsets used for scanning barcodes and a lot more.
The barcode scanners currently implemented are working correctly for:

- iOS device using a scan jacket
- Zebra handset device (Android)

Now, there is a request to use new handset devices (Android) called ASCOM Myco 3 and I had no luck finding drivers or DLL files or documentation on how to get it to work on my Xamarin/C# App.

Does anyone have experience with that? All I need is to be able to scan a barcode.

Thanks

Comment: A common practice is to set the embedded barcode scanner to keyboard input emulation mode. Is there such an option in the documentation such as SDK? If that doesn't work, ask your device vendor how to use it with Xamarin. If that's not the case, you might want to find out how to use the scanner with Xamarin from scratch, or switch to a device from a vendor that offers such an option.

Comment: Thank you @kunif - I have sent an email the vendor to understand if they have any suggestions.